# Rails missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've worked a bit on Rails before but this is the first time I'm working on Rails 4 (not that I believe its the problem).

I have the following routes in my routes.rb

```
match "/admin/login" => "admin#login", :as => :admin_login, :via => [:get,:post]
```

When I visit /admin/login, the file at admin/login.html.erb renders properly. But when I do a redirection like -

```
redirect_to :admin_login
```

I get an error -

```
Missing template admin/admin_login, application/admin_login
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The :as option forms a named route.

Usually it's used in a non-root route.

Try this

```
redirect_to admin_login_path
```

`admin_login_path` and `admin_login_url` are defined because of the :as

Comment: Perfect! I'm almost too embarrassed to admit it but I remember facing this issue the last I worked on a Rails project. Time to hit the docs again it seems.